# if $RA$ is context-free, is $A$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

> If $RA$ is context-free for a regular language R, is $A$ context-free?

I think this statement is true. Let G be the CFG given by the rules $S_0\mapsto LA_1, S\mapsto LA_1, A_1\mapsto SA_2 | RS | 1, A_2\mapsto RS | 1, L\mapsto 0, R\mapsto 1$, where $S_0$ is the start symbol. How would one modify G to get a CFG that generates the same grammar but with $0$ removed from the front of every string? Clearly the only way a derivation in G could generate a string starting with 0 is if it contains one of the nonterminals $L,S,A_1$. So one should probably mark these nonterminals somehow and then modify the rules containing these nonterminals on the RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\Sigma^*A=\Sigma^*$ is a regular language, where $A$ is any language that contains the empty string. So, given language $A$, the existence of an regular language $R$ such that $RA$ is regular (and hence also context-free) does not imply $A$ is context-free. Nor does it does imply $A$ is context-sensitive, etc.

If $R$ is meant to be any regular language, then letting $R=\{\epsilon\}$, we see the condition implies $A=\{\epsilon\}A$ is a regular language (and hence also context-free).

Comment: Thanks. I think there's a notion of a "left quotient though." For instance, I think that if R is regular and $A$ is context free, then $\{a : \exists r, ra\in A\}$ is context free.